# What is the natural way to say "increment by 0.5"?

Tags: grammar, numbers

I have a digital scale. The number on the display goes up like 0.0kg, 0.5kg, 1.0kg, 1.5kg... What are good ways to describe this?

My ideas are below.

1. This can scale every 0.5kg.
2. The number increments by 0.5.
3. This can scale weight in the increments of 0.5.

Comment: 'This scale is marked every 0·5kg'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it's a digital scale weighing device), if I read the question correctly. I would stay 'this scale measure weight in 0.5 kg steps'. (Aren't those a bit large? I wouldn't use such a device for anything important.)

Comment: "This scale can weigh in 0.5kg increments".

Comment: @Michael Harvey Yes, you're right. I'm thinking back to when 'digital' meant 'involving digits' rather than 'non-analogue'. The typical old-fashioned bathroom scale. As opposed to semi-quantitative << marked 'full' ... ... ... 'approaching empty' ... 'empty' >> on a fuel gauge. But of course the default meaning nowadays _is_ non-analogue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I was thinking of 'involving digits'. I have a 1970s electric clock that had no hands, but rather a pair of revolving drums, one with numbers 0-12, and the other with 0-59 around the edges, showing through two rectangular apertures, revolved by an electric motor via gears, where the numbers shown for the hours and minutes flipped from one to the next mechanically and there is not a single piece of 'digital electronics' in sight, Until recently my house had an electricity meter that showed kilowatt hours the same way, all done by a revolving wheel and lots of little gears.

Comment: The scale has a resolution of 0.5 kg.

Comment: Informally, I might say it "goes up in halves" (like shoe sizes).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The mechanical electricity and gas meters I've had (apart from the really old ones with counter-rotating dials) have all had a cylinder with red numbers showing tenths of a unit. Each cylinder has had a period between each pair of numbers where it moved gradually from one number to the next only becoming fixed when the number showed completely. Having said that the meters and clocks with cylindrical mechanical tumblers were called 'digital' when they were introduced, the idea that 'digital' is a synonym for 'electronic' is comparatively recent.

Comment: @BoldBen - I don't consider 'digital' to be a synonym for 'electronic', maybe that's because I got my radio ham licence at the age of 14 in 1966, and worked on analog computers in an early job. I vividly remember 'cosine potentiometers'.

Comment: I think we have the same view but many younger people do not. If you suggested to them that a mechanical meter with tumblers was digital they'd look at you as though you were stupid!

Comment: @BoldBen - round about the time when digital watches were a new thing, in the 1980s, there was a cartoon in Mad magazine showing a father showing his son his old watch with hands, and the kid is saying "But it says the time is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 o'clock!".

Comment: @BoldBen - the past is truly a foreign country to young folk. I remember my son (who had, supposedly,  spent a year studying 20th century history at school) asking me what Queen Victoria thought of Hitler.